# Drive name red in Disk Utility: Core Storage Drive offline. How to bring back?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, ssd, disk-utility

Yesterday, my mac wouldn't boot up.  When I restarted, I could get the whole way to the User login screen.  No matter what user I chose, the boot bar would get about 1/3 way finished and I would get the circle with the line through it (prohibitory sign).

I couldn't boot into recovery, and internet recovery > Disk Utility would hang on "checking prerequisites".

The disk in questions is an SSD called "My HD"

So I booted into Yosemite on an external drive.  That's where I'm currently writing this. Disk Utility found My HD but the name was red. Clicking "Verify" or "Repair" did nothing. Everything on the partition tab was greyed out. Hovering over the disk name said "Core Storage Drive Offline".

In terminal `diskutil cs list` returned nothing. `distutil list` returned all my drives except My HD.

So I restarted.  Now the drive is nowhere to be found. If I go into System Information, it's not listed under "storage" and under SATA, I have "Intel 6 Series Chipset > Unknown"

I don't have a clue what the next step is to fixing this issue. Is my disk completely gone / unrecoverable?

Comment: I'm afraid to say, the drive may be gone

Comment: nothing I can do to verify that?

Comment: I think the 'verification' is the rapid decline in what you can see of it. Maybe pull it out, drop it in a USB enclosure; see if it's visible without SMART getting in the way, perhaps